# Testing async POST requests that go into queue to be processed with JMeter

Tags: api, testing, asynchronous, jmeter

Using Jmeter I am attempting to load test async POST requests. Once a request gets made, a mongoDB documents gets put into a worker farm queue to be processed. I do not want my thread to move forward until that queue gets processed. Is there a way to wait for the status of that to complete.

My thread steps look like this.

1. Log in
2. Create event (POST)
3. Add video to event (POST)
4. Process event (async POST) "This is the request that puts the video in a queue for processing, I can do a GET on the event and see the status of the video which is "status" : "Encoding" or "status" : "Ready"."
5. Watch video (GET)
6. Delete event (DELETE)

I tried adding a while controller in my thread to keep checking the event status and only move out if the status is Ready but that didn't seem to work as it only loops 3 times and then did nothing, I may be using it wrong though.

This is what my while controller looks like.

```
While Controller w/ condition ${__javaScript(${status}!="Ready")}
    GET Event Status
        HTTP Header Manager
        Json Path Extractor for status - $.status
        Constant Timer - 1000
```

Has anybody had a similar problem with async calls? Or through out some ideas on how to get around this?

Thanks

Comment: a while loop controller is the way to go. how are you configuring it? Show the test plan and it should be fairly easy to help you along. Main problem is getting the condition right in the while controller. Might also be worth putting a sleep or wait into your loop so it doesn't fill the server with status requests.

Comment: I got the while controller to work but on the first request the controller makes it returns a 200 like it should but if it needs to loop again same request then returns a 304? Don't understand why this is happening? I edited my questions to show what Im doing with the while controller

Comment: whats the header manager doing, do you really need it? 304 is server response based on specific request contents. can you show the two sample requests and responses that you expect to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Thread Group 1
Beanshell Sampler - props.put("finish", "FALSE");
HTTP1
HTTP2
....
Loop and/or delay (GET on the event and see the status of the video which is "status" : "Encoding" or "status" : "Ready".")
IF Controller - "${status}"=="Ready"
        Beanshell Sampler - props.put("finish", "TRUE");

While Controller - ${__BeanShell( props.get("finish") != null || props.get("finish")=="TRUE" )}
                 Watch video (GET)
                Delete event (DELETE)

hope this will help.

Comment: Are you saying to put the IF Controller, Beanshell Sampler and While Controller all under the Loop?

Comment: no, only get request to check the status should be in IF controller